# Go benchmark tests DONT measure only the loop?

Tags: go, benchmarking

In my Go benchmark test, I have some init code that sets up test data and then I have the benchmarking loop like below. It seems the output measures runtime of whole function, not just whats in the loop. Thats not useful info for me. Is there a way to enforce measuring runtime of only loop contents since thats what I am concerned with? Shouldnt that be obvious?

```
func BenchmarkXXX(b *testing.B){
// Some test data init code..

for i:=0; i < b.N; i++ {
      //benchmarking code..
}
```

Comment: Can you init outside that function and have the benchmark function re-read the same data repeatedly?  Or does it have to modify data in-place?

Answer (score 7):

you will be able to do this by calling `b.ResetTimer()` after your "test data init code".

```
func BenchmarkXXX(b *testing.B){
    // Some test data init code..

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i:=0; i < b.N; i++ {
        //benchmarking code..
    }
}
```

See [Benchmarks](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).